# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:Resource not found

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I try to use subreport using *JasperSoft Studio* but I get the exception below. It cannot find the subreport file although it is there.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:Resource not found at: D:\\JASPERREPORTS\\MyReports
```

Below is the configuration of main report

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0a6d6643-1d79-4e5e-b39d-a773bba37c12">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="kai3_adapter"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from cm_crew]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="OID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="CREW_OID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CONTACT_OID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="ACTIVE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ONSHIFT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIFT_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIFT_START" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="CREW_STATUS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="CREW_OID">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{CREW_OID}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="141" height="20" uuid="fc7cf2eb-2922-42e3-b446-fa1cba3239d6"/>
                <text><![CDATA[CREW_OID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="141" y="0" width="138" height="20" uuid="1fb08aed-592e-437d-9c3c-87e763dc81f8"/>
                <text><![CDATA[ACTIVE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="279" y="0" width="138" height="20" uuid="76eaa47f-6f18-4210-a607-a6456b1cc4ed"/>
                <text><![CDATA[ONSHIFT]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="417" y="0" width="138" height="20" uuid="273fca2c-2b50-4157-ab3b-8545d94855f3"/>
                <text><![CDATA[CREW_STATUS]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="257" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="13" width="141" height="20" uuid="ef3acaa1-b11a-4b3d-b90d-7da18fc15dfa"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CREW_OID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="141" y="13" width="138" height="20" uuid="2c29e96a-d712-4aff-9449-46f523ebbad8"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ACTIVE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="279" y="13" width="81" height="20" uuid="70df46c9-e63a-45a0-8c6e-82e38c260681"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ONSHIFT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="380" y="20" width="165" height="170" uuid="3c312fc6-a389-4e46-af09-ddb1bfaa353f"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["D:\\JASPERREPORTS\\MyReports\\"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following Sharad's answer, if it still doesn't generate the file (which happened to me), you can try this:

Before previewing the report, you can try to compile it first. If you open your jrxml file (the one that includes the subreport), you may notice a little icon (a little file with some binary string) on the upper bar of your editor. Clicking this button should generate the file you're expecting.

I created a new answer because I wanted to add an image showing the button:

[image: Compile button @ Jaspersoft Studio 5.6]

Notice that this may also work: clean the projects that contain the reports using "Project > Clean...". And then right click your project in the "Project Explorer" (usually on your left), and then click "Build Project".

Answer (score 3):

Send the `"SUBREPORT_DIR"` parameter from the application that calls the report.
For example, in Java:

```
params.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", "reports/folder/");
```

Just point to the directory, not the file.

If you use Maven, set Maven resource tags properly in `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the subreport name in the subreport path like this :-

```
 "D:\\JASPERREPORTS\\MyReports\\subreport.jasper"
```

Even .jasper file is not there just give the subreport.jasper it will automatically compile the subreport.jrxml file and generate the .jasper file.

Comment: It didnt change anything. Furthermore, there is no file with extension .jasper. Although I open subreport with preview mode, it doesnt create any .jasper file.

Comment: Just give subreportname.jasper even if that is not there. but see whether sureport is running or not.

Comment: If there is not any jasper file, you have a problem in compilation. If you are sure of your report, then reinstall ireport. the most stable version of ireport is 4.5.0